# My ASP.NET results are different

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am developing an ASP.NET project for our intranet which retrieves client's MachineName and IPAddress and I am using the following code.

**ajax/default.aspx.vb**

```
Public Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Request.QueryString.Count > 0 Then
        Select Case Request.QueryString("eval")

            Case Else
                Dim type As Type = type.GetType("ajax_default")
                Dim method As MethodInfo = type.GetMethod("zzfxn_" & Request.QueryString("eval").ToString, BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance)
                If method IsNot Nothing Then
                    method.Invoke(Me, New Object() {Request})
                End If
        End Select
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub zzfxn_zGetClientInfo(ByVal r As System.Web.HttpRequest)
    Response.Write("Client IP Address: " & Request.UserHostName & "|" & Request.UserHostAddress & "<br />")
    Response.Write("Client Machine Name: " & System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.UserHostName).HostName.Split(".")(0))
End Sub
```

**test/Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">.hid{display: none;}</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" runat="server">
         <div>
            <p>My client info is: <%= InvokeAjax("?eval=zGetClientInfo")%></p>
         </div>
     </form>
     <script type="text/VB" runat="server">
        Protected Function InvokeAjax(ByVal params As String) As String
            Dim wc As New System.Net.WebClient
            wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", Request.UserAgent)
            Dim ru As String = Request.Url.ToString.Remove(Request.Url.ToString.IndexOf("/test")) & "/ajax/default.aspx"
            Return wc.DownloadString(ru & params).ToString
        End Function
    </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I deployed the project to the ***test-server*** Windows Server 2000, ASP.NET 4 and I got the following results.

Running/viewing **ajax/Default.aspx?eval=zGetClientInfo** results to:

```
Client IP Address: 10.20.10.5|10.20.10.5
Client Machine Name: devctr
```

Running/viewing **test/Default.aspx** results to:

```
My client info is: Client IP Address: 10.20.10.60|10.20.10.60
Client Machine Name: test-server
```

*10.20.10.5* or *devctr* is my machine so viewing directly to ajax/default.aspx returns the exact/true content, while *10.20.10.60* or *test-server* is my host/server.

Can someone please explain to me why they differ?
And how can I achieve the results of ajax/defaut.aspx to be exactly the same for test/Default.aspx?

Comment: Your server is calling the ajax, not the client. Why do you need ajax when the server is running it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the test/Default.aspx example, you are creating a web request that is originating on the server, hence the "runat='server'" parameter.  If you are trying to create an ajax request that originates from the client, you will need to use a client side script like javascript.  You could use jQuery to do this by doing something like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/?eval=zGetClientInfo"
}).done(function(data) {
  //Set your html here
});
```

If you are really going to do this, however, I would consider looking into ASP.NET Web API.  Your solution will be much more robust if you return your results in some sort of JSON or XML format, which web API will do.

Comment: Unfortunately, not all web browser, especially lower versions of IE, supports jQuery library. I already used that method and I gave up using it due to that problem. Most of our users still runs lower machines and uses default web browsers so using plain ASP.NET will work.

Comment: Wow, you have people using IE 5 or earlier?  That's like 15 years old.

Comment: I think we are still using IE6 as the oldest browser. Not all machines are connected to the web.

Comment: jQuery is supported on IE6.  Regardless, you will need to create the request from the client, so if it's not jQuery it will need to be plain javascript.  This is all assuming you need to do this thing in an Ajax manner.  Why not simply fill in the information on the original page request, why do it via ajax?

Comment: A lot of problems pops out when it comes to jQuery for older version and as what I have said earlier, most of our machines are old and I am not expecting they have JRE. It will be much easier for me if I will just create a stand-alone desktop application but we have hundreds of machines and updating the software one-by-one will be difficult and way to timely. ASP.NET will be much easier for maintenance.

Comment: If you don't want to use JavaScript than Ajax isn't an option and you will need to set these values on the initial page load.  Also, you don't need JRE to do JavaScript.

Comment: @pvzkch what version of jQuery did you try on the older machines? Don't use jQuery 2.x for  web apps targeting older browsers as It is only designed for modern browesers. Use 1.x instead, it is still current and actively developed. In a nutshell use 1.x versions of jquery unless you only want to support modern browsers.

Comment: @JonP I used jQuery1.10.2, jQuery-ui 1.10.4.

Comment: @sonofaforester Doing few research on IE, I found out that IE6 supports Javascript1.5 and jQuery lib says they support IE6+ on version 1.x which matches to what I used. I read a blog from jQuery stating that they gave up supporting old browser such as IE, another reason I stopped using jQuery library.